# Drawing of Fragment is lagging my loading animation

Tags: android, kotlin, animationdrawable

I am using `AnimationDrawable` to show loading. Something like this:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loader_00000" android:duration="12" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loader_00001" android:duration="12" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loader_00002" android:duration="12" />
    ...
</animation-list>
```

I am using `Fragment`. I have this animation in `ImageView` as src and I am showing it above the content of `fragment_layout`.

I am running animation like this:

```
(image_view.drawable as AnimationDrawable).start()
```

Animation works quite well. But I am loading stuff from a server and populating it to components below animation. I am loading stuff in a background thread. Using `CoroutineScope` with `Dispatchers.IO`. However, populating of stuff is causing lagging of my animation. How can I improve it to not lag? Is it possible? Is there a better approach?

Comment: First of all what you are doing seems normal, BUT: Performance questions are particularly hard to answer, without the whole picture, e.g. the exact images, the code to populate the fragment and the device etc. I recommend that you use the [profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler) to analyse the problem and to see what code makes you break the 16ms barrier. If you want a profound answer to your problem please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Have you tried to lower the background thread priority?